# How to execute a script Perl with mozilla with Bitnami LAMP Stack?

Tags: apache, perl, ubuntu, lamp, bitnami

I downloaded LAMP Stack from Bitnami web site as Ubuntu VM. I'm not expert, and I've some difficultes. I created a perl script as CGI called prova.cgi : it is a simple hello world. Now I have to execute it using mozilla (in windows), keeping alive the bitnami VM: I write: `http://192.168.88.129/opt/bitnami/apache2/cgi-bin/prova.cgi` but the result is:
Not Found
The requested URL /opt/bitnami/apache2/cgi-bin/prova.cgi was not found on this server.

Maybe I'm making an error about the location in which my script is supposed to stay: I put it in /opt/bitnami/apache2/cgi-bin/.

Any Suggestion?
Regards, Matteo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Not Found" means exactly what it says on the tin.

What's going on, is apache is configured with a scripting location - the precise details will be in your `httpd.conf`. When you access a *url* of an appropriate type, apache will redirect the request and run the script.

I will guess in this case - you need to fetch `http://192.168.88.129/cgi-bin/prova.cgi`

But to be sure, you'd need to check your `httpd.conf`.

Comment: You guess right! I've just a problem: the output is the code of the script! I think that it doesn't manage to find the Perl interpreter.. Teorically I am using Lamp Stack so I don't have to touch configuration file..

Comment: No, it's simpler. It's reading it, not running it. This means it's not in the right place.

Comment: Dunno.. I followed all the step of a start guide and all seems ok... i modifyed the httpd.conf like the guide but nothing happen..

Comment: What does your `ScriptAlias` say?

Comment: It says: 
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/opt/bitnami/apache2/cgi-bin/"

And the configuration that I've written is:
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache2/cgi-bin"> 
AllowOverride None 
Require all granted 
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl 
Options +ExecCGI 
</Directory>